# Hp-Ux.Shell.Using variables in "if"

Tags: shell, hp-ux

Recently I've got confused by the following situation.
What is the difference between two `if` usage:

*Case 1*

```
amount=10  
if [[ $amount -eq 10 ]]   
then  
    echo "something"  
fi
```

script output:

```
$ ./1.sh  
something
```

*Case 2*

```
if [[ amount -eq 10 ]]
```

This also works like this (note that the variable name doesn't contain the `$`).

So the question is how does it work even without dollar sign in the variable name.

P.S. I'm using a POSIX shell on HP-UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man bash`

> ARITHMETIC EVALUATION
>   ...
>   Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion  is  per‐
>          formed  before  the  expression  is  evaluated.  Within an expression,
>          shell variables may also be  referenced  by  name  without  using  the
>          parameter  expansion  syntax.

In this context shell does not expect anything but numerics, so it expands strings as variables. That makes sense to me.